# Does Chrome have a native TTS?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, tts

Windows has a native TTS (Text to Speech) program called Narrator, it can easily be [enabled to read a specific paragraph on a text document.](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-the-speak-text-to-speech-feature-to-read-text-aloud-459e7704-a76d-4fe2-ab48-189d6b83333c)

When I looked around to see if Chrome had a similar program that I could use when surfing, I found a bunch of add on apps and this post 
[Realistic voice for Text-to-Speech](https://superuser.com/questions/518448/realistic-voice-for-text-to-speech/570204#570204)

I want to know if there is something in Chrome that is no an addon that I can use, and if so how to turn it on

Comment: This is the point where MS Edge overtakes Chrome.

Answer (score 3):

While Chrome does have built-in TTS functionality (see [chrome.tts - Google Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tts)), it appears that an extension is required to utilize it. Google does have its own [ChromeVox extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chromevox/kgejglhpjiefppelpmljglcjbhoiplfn).

Comment: I was on chrome canary and hoped I could do this without an extension. Searched chrome://flags but no dice.